# php database display in webpage

Tags: php, css

How can I apply a css to `$row["name"]` and display it in a table?
Here is my code:

```
<div class="maincontent1">
                <?php
                $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","webpage2")  or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); 
                $sql = "SELECT id, name, description1 FROM table1";
                $result = $link->query($sql);
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
                    {
                    // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                        { 

                    ?>
                            <div class="title-style1">
                            <?php 
                                echo $row["name"];
                            ?>
                            </div>      
                    <?php
                        echo $row["description1"];
                        }
                        $link->close();
                    }
                        ?>
```

Comment: *how can give css to $row["name"]* - what `css`? For printing them in `table` just replace the `div`s accordingly.

Comment: Please explain what output you needed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear about what you are saying about css, but if you want your data to print in a table then you can do something like this

```
   <table>      
        <tr>

           <th>
              Name
           </th>
           <th>
              Description
           </th> 
       </tr>
    <?php
                        $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","webpage2")  or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); 
                        $sql = "SELECT id, name, description1 FROM table1";
                        $result = $link->query($sql);
                        if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
                            {
                            // output data of each row
                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                    { 
                     ?>
                               <tr>
                                    <div class="title-style1">
                              <td>      <?php 
                                        echo $row["name"];
                                    ?>

                              </td>
                             <td>
                                  <?php
                                      echo $row["description1"];
                                  ?>
                             </td>
                         </div>  
                             </tr>  
                             <?php
                               }
                                $link->close();

                            }
                                ?>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

To can try something like this :

```
   <div class="maincontent1">
           <?php
                    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","webpage2")  or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); 
                    $sql = "SELECT id, name, description1 FROM table1";
                    $result = $link->query($sql);
                    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
           ?>
      <div class="title-style1">
         <table name="table" border: 1px solid black ; cellspacing='0'>
           <thead>
                 <tr>
                     <th style= "" > Name </th> // you can put the style you want here
                     <th style= "" > Description </th> 
                 </tr>
           </thead>
                 <?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
                      <td style=""> <?php echo $row['name'];?></td> //style here
                      <td style=""> <?php echo $row['description1'];?></td> //style here

                    <?php 
                        }

                    ?>
        </table>
<?php } 
     $link->close();
?>
```

if you want to can just have a external css so you will just call it. I hope this helps.